# html5 / css3 :disabled pseudo class - working? how to display? what effects does it have?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

css3 pseudo class :disabled

is this supported yet - thought it was but cannot make it fly in chrome

- tried setting div.disabled = true;
- tried setting div.endabled = false;

still no joy

if wish to show an entire DIV disabled, how can I darken "gray out" the entire DIV without knowing its background colors?

if the DIV is disabled, are INPUT's and A(nchor)s contained therein disabled as well?

---

my solution: cover the area of the page to be disabled with a translucent page with a higher z-index - this prevents any interaction with the page below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure you can't add a disabled attribute to a `<div>` tag, only `<input />`, `<fieldset>` and `<command>` tags. Maybe try adding a `<fieldset disabled>` around your `<input />` elements instead?
2. Use rgba colours or opacity to give your disabled element(s) a faded out look, or hsl colours and reduce the saturation to give the disabled element(s) a black-and-white look
3. If you use `<fieldset disabled>` I think it will disable all `<input />` elements contained within it.

Comment: fieldset - outstanding idea!  will test and ensure

Comment: have never used opacity or hsl colours - will play with opacity

Comment: opacity works great! esp with transitions to soften the effect.

Comment: @cc young Just tried a quick test of <fieldset disabled> in Firefox 4 and it worked for me. Which browser(s) are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Best answer to your question is in the definition of what a disabled element is.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#pseudo-disabled

> 2.1.3 The :disabled pseudo-class
>
> Similar to :enabled, :disabled allows
>   the author to specify precisely how a
>   disabled or inactive user interface
>   element should look.
>
> It should be noted that most elements
>   will be neither enabled nor disabled.
>   An element is enabled if the user can
>   either activate it or transfer the
>   focus to it. An element is disabled if
>   it could be enabled, but the user
>   cannot presently activate it or
>   transfer focus to it.

:disabled is supported in Chrome - check jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/zCVGV/3/

Comment: " An element is enabled if the user can either activate it or transfer the focus to it" - that sort of leaves out divs.

Comment: Correct - The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the content.

Answer (score 0):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) includes the `:disabled` selector in its table of compatibility.

According to that table, the style is widely supported in all browsers, except IE, where it only got added recently with IE9.

However, you can use the `attr` selector to do the same thing:

```
.myclass[disabled] { .... }
```

is (virtually) the same as

```
.myclass:disabled { .... }
```

with the benefit that it works in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: thanks for the quirksmode link - I did not know it was being actively maintained - some of the info I had seen I had thought was stale

Comment: @CC young: yes, it is a bit stale (I tend to use http://CanIUse.com more than quirksmode these days), but the info for `disabled` is still relevant and correct. (FWIW, quirksmode.org is still actively maintained, but the author has switched focus toward mobile browsing, so his original compatibility tables for desktop browsers have become a bit stale, but he's got loads of info for developing mobile sites)

Comment: that's great news - quirksmode and mobile browsing - thanks in advance